# How should I interpret this int initialization?

Tags: c#

I've been programming C# for some months now but I've never encountered this till now; what does this instruction mean?

```
int a = 1, b;
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not according to the standards hold by site. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's same as:

```
int a = 1;
int b;
```

Answer (score 4):

Above statement declare multiple variables of same datatype in single statement.

> So A local variable declaration that declares multiple variables is equivalent to multiple declarations of single variables with the same type.

That means

```
int a=1, b;
```

indicates that `a` and `b` both has same data type i.e. `int` along with we initialize the variable `a` with value `1` and `b` has default int value i.e `0`

So equivalently you can write it as

```
int a=1;
int b;
```

Comment: Whether we can say b has a value of zero is entirely dependent on whether it is a field or a local

Comment: If `b` is a local variable then it does not have the value 0 since local variables are not initialised to a default value. You can't even read the value of `b` until it has been definitely assigned, so `int b; Console.WriteLine(b);` will not compile.

Comment: @Lee well, actually we *can* find the value (by cheating - can't do it just from c#), and as it happens the value will be zero on MS .NET CLI. But we have to use implementation details to do this. At the language level alone: indeed, it has no defined value

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether these are "locals" (method variables) or "fields" (instance variables).

For fields, it declares a and b as Int32; they are both initiaized to zero when the memory is wiped (newobj/initobj) prior to the constructor being called, and then a is assigned a value of 1 at the start of the constructor.

For locals, it declares a and b as Int32, and immediately assigns 1 to a. B has no defined value. The rules of "definite assignment" mean that it is not required to have a defined value. However, all values on the stack must have *some* value - and we could obtain that value by cheating (for example, writing a method in IL that implements "out", but simply dereferences the address). The actual value is Dependent on whether the init-locals flag is set. This is not a c# language feature, but the current compiler does include this flag. This means that the memory space for locals is erased (set to zero) at the start of the method. So the logical value will be zero, but for different reasons. There is no requirement for this to happen - so it is entirely an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

It defines Integers "a" and "b" giving value 1 to a

Comment: It only defines but does not initialize `b`.

Comment: You're right, bad choice of words on my side :)

Answer (score 1):

a and b are integers

and a's value is one. b has no value yet

Comment: @Vlad that depends on whether these are fields or locals. If they are locals, it has no defined value. What the value *actually* is depends on the  CLI implementation. There is no required value from a language perspective. But it will usually be zero, if you peek under the covers - but for reasons that make "has a value 0" misleading, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

a was declared and initialized to zero while b was just declared.